# Joomla 3 - Pagination limit

Tags: php, joomla, joomla3.0

I am trying to override the standard Joomla pagination. Instead of showing 10 links then the next / end links, I would like to show 20 links up front.

Is this possible?

Thanks

Comment: Please ask your Joomla related questions over at [Joomla Stack Exchange](http://joomla.stackexchange.com) :)

Comment: Where are you trying to override? In a custom component?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible.

1. Log into your Joomla 3.0 Control Panel.
2. Click the link labeled Global Configuration.
3. Under the Site Settings heading, find the setting labeled Default List Limit. Use the drop down menu to make your desired change, and then click the Save button in the top left of the page.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if the answer by @Garima is correct. The default list limit is to specify how many items are to be displayed by default in the backend.

To solve your problem, you will need to override the libraries/joomla/html/pagination.php file to display 20 links at the bottom instead of 10.

Comment: That is what I understood.@user2713512, itoctopus:- Please correct me If I understood wrong. So that I can suggest another solution for this.

Comment: The default list limit is global, i.e. you set it once and it controlls front and backend list views.